# CSS border-image not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have used CSS `border-image` to attain certain effect in the menu bar. Its working good in Firefox. But doesn't work in Chrome.

See [www.imptools.com](http://www.imptools.com). Is there any workaround for chrome?

**CSS**

```
nav.mainMenu{
width:@16cols; height: 50px;
margin:0 auto; position: relative;
top:-25px;
ul{
    width:100%; height:50px; overflow: visible;
    background: url('../imgs/gun_metal.png');
    border-radius: 15px; box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px @dark;

    li{
        float:left; width: auto;
        margin: 0 20px; overflow: visible;
        height: 80px; position:relative; top:-15px;
        a{
            width: auto; height: auto;
            float:left; padding: 0 15px;
            font-family: @sansSec;
            color:@light;
            line-height: 80px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px @dark;
        }
    }
    li.active, li:hover{
        background: @primary;
        border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
        border-image:url(../imgs/menu_active_bg.png);   
        border-image-width:15px 15px 0px 0px;
        border-image-outset: 0px 15px;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Try setting the border before setting the image like so

```
border: 50px solid transparent;
```

I have noticed that in Safari this statement doesn't matter but it does matter in chrome

Comment: Yep, Chrome 51 fixed a bug here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5542503914668032

Comment: This fixed it for me - over two years later!  Thanks!

Comment: This actually _breaks_ `border-image` in Safari for me. Apparently `border-color: transparent;` takes priority over `border-image-source`. But setting `border: 50px solid` before `border-image-source` seems to work nicely for both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

According to [chrome platform status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5542503914668032),

> Blink will begin to require a border style in order to paint border images. This has always been required by the spec, but has not been enforced. In order to not be affected by this change, add e.g. 'border-style: solid' where border-image is used.

so adding

```
border-style: solid;
```

should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
li.active, li:hover{
    background: @primary;
    border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    border-image:url(../imgs/menu_active_bg.png);   
    -webkit-border-image:url(../imgs/menu_active_bg.png);   
    -moz-border-image:url(../imgs/menu_active_bg.png);   
    -khtml-border-image:url(../imgs/menu_active_bg.png);   
    border-image-width:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-image-width:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-image-width:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    -khtml-border-image-width:15px 15px 0px 0px;
    border-image-outset: 0px 15px;
    -webkit-border-image-outset: 0px 15px;
    -moz-border-image-outset: 0px 15px;
    -khtml-border-image-outset: 0px 15px;
}
```

Comment: this webkit work only for border-radius. But I need for border image. compare the menu in firefox and chorme for difference.

Comment: Looks like "-webkit-border-image" also might exist, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: -webkit-border-image-width: and -webkit-border-image-outset:  is not recognized by chrome

Comment: look at question I have added the image. Thats how i need it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like below.

```
li.active, li:hover{
background: @primary;
border-radius: 15px 0 15px 15px;
border-image:url('../imgs/menu_active_bg.png') 100% 100% 0% 0% / 15px 15px 0px 0px / 0 15px 0 0px;
-webkit-border-image:url('../imgs/menu_active_bg.png') 100% 100% 0% 0% / 15px 15px 0px 0px / 0 15px 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: same result, no change.

Comment: i checked in your site via chrome dev tools and it shows fine. Not sure where you are checking.

Comment: I am checking it locally. I'll try it again.

Comment: look at question I have added the image. Thats how i need it.